# Mosquitto Configuration on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, security

I installed the MQTT mosquitto package from the standard repos on a fresh 16.04. I'm confused about where to place/edit the conf file for MQTT to work with a username and password.

There is a conf file in /etc/mosquitto/ however in reading that file it says to place "your" conf file in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/. The conf file in /etc/mosquitto looks like the one you are supposed to edit. I tried editing that file and simply creating a new one and putting it in the place that was mentioned but nothing seemed to work.

There is an example conf but it is in /var/share/doc/mosquitto/.

If anyone familiar with running mosquitto on Ubuntu could chime it it would be helpful. I thought the config should be straight forward you put in the line to set anonymous connections to false and then set the path to your pwd file but I seem to either be putting it in the wrong place or using it incorrectly.

Comment: Don't do anything like that next time, just use the example Configuration to make yours and put it where instructed instead of poking the one in /etc/mosquito, Maybe that one is automatically made from /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/ Good luck! Tell me if that works.

Comment: You were right. I make the mistake of trying to overthink it. I reinstalled and put the config in the designated place without touching the top level one and it worked fine. Not sure what is going on there but I won't complain. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are not over thinking actually. You're trying to be resourceful. But don't do that like a Kamikaze YOLO, there's two useful commands, to use them make an USB live image where you will install the SW or programs you want to learn. After installation of the desired packages use "info program" and the "man program" commands from the terminal in that order. Some programs may not have this pages. If so then ask the developers or go to their homepage. Happy Llamas!

Answer (score 0):

I made the mistake of trying to edit the conf I found in the /etc/mosquitto directory. The answer is to leave that .conf alone and to go to the conf.d directory and to create your custom directory there.